# Error when I try to upload a much smaller file than the upload limit on drupal 7

Tags: sqlite, drupal, file-upload, image-upload

When I try to upload a 200KB file, for example, I get an error message saying the file is bigger than 8MB. When I try to upload a 10KB image, the upload process complets successfully.

I am using Drupal 7, SQLite as database engine, and the upload limit in php.ini is 8MB; the server is hosted on hordeeasy.com.

Can someone give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a problem with your webserver/hosting.

File uploads are limited in two ways when using drupal with apache:

- Php/apache enforced limit
- Drupal enforced software limit

If you can get to your php.ini, check these settings are correct:

```
 post_max_size = 20M

 upload_max_file = 20M
```